# Binding array to model from directive

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I'm able to bind a standalone string in this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/GKZHSDe5J0eCzqlgaf4g?p=preview

However when attempting the same but with an array of strings, the model no longer updates: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fz9GFxWeZxRpsiqXgra4?p=preview

This is the directive code:

```
app.directive('psDIR', [
    function() {
        return {
            template: "<div ng-init=\"models=['yp', 'hi']\" style='padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red; margin-bottom: 10px;'><p>This is a direcive:</p> <textarea ng-repeat=\"md in models\" rows='5' cols='50' ng-model='md'></textarea></div>",
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {models:'=model'},
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
              scope.$watchCollection('scope.models', function(){
                  console.log(scope.models);
              });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

What am I doing wrong that the model no longer matches the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.directive('psDIR', [
    function() {
        return {
            template: "<div ng-init=\"models=['']\"><textarea ng-repeat=\"md in models track by $index\" ng-model='models[$index]'></textarea></div> {{validation}}",
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {validation: '@', models:'=model'},
            link: function (scope) {
              scope.$watchCollection('models', function(){
                console.log(scope.models);
              });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```